# Event listener don't work

Tags: jquery, events, dom

I have the next selector "#btn-similar", why this listener works:

```
$("#btn-similar").click(function(e){
   console.log("similar click");
});
```

But this listener not:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn-similar", function(e){
   console.log("similar click");
});
```

The HTML markup is:

```
<div id="btn-similar" class="details-tab active-nav">
   <span class="angle"></span>
   <div class="title">Overview</div>
</div>
```

I am using jQuery 1.10, any ideas ?

Comment: if you use jquery version below 1.7 on is not working? go with .live()

Answer (score 0):

Since both pieces of code are correct and would work in most circumstances, I can only think of these reasons why the second one would not work:

1. There's an `<a>` tag or a form post in the hierarchy that is causing the browser to go to a new page before the results of your code can be seen.
2. You have more than one object in the page with `id=btn-similar`.
3. There's a script error right before your second block of code that keeps it from executing.
4. You have a typo somewhere and the code doesn't actually match the desired id.  In your question, you show code that refers to `id=btn-similar`, but the code is `id=btn-overview`.

FYI, you can see the second block of code work just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8s7rukt3/ so there's obviously some oddity in your page that you haven't disclosed.

Comment: @ramiromd - did you figure out the problem?